# Sharepoint: On time up, form should save

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I am making a quiz on sharepoint and on timer finish I want to save whatever data user has entered already

Javascript for timer:

```
<p>Count down</p>
<p id="demo"></p>



<script>
//declare variables
var hours =0;
var minutes =1;
var seconds=30;
var timer=setInterval(function(){myCounter()},1000);
function myCounter()
{
     seconds--;
     if(seconds==0)
        {
          minutes=minutes-1;
          seconds=60;
        }
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=minutes +":"+seconds;
         if(minutes==0)
             {
               clearTimeout(timer);
               document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Time's Up!";
window.location.replace("http://sharepoint:15410/IPDP/Marketing/SitePages/Time%20is%20Up.aspx");

             }
}
</script>
```

How can I save page on time close? Please help
[image]

Comment: In simple word, Use REST or JSOM to save data to list, or try document.getElementById("save_button_id").click()  .... what is the problem you are facing ....

Comment: I tried document.getElementById("save_button_id").click() not working :(

Comment: timer stuck in this case to 0:60